# Is this grammatically correct- "My husband came running when he heard me call out for help."

Tags: grammar

"My husband came running when he heard me call out for help."

In the above sentence, should there be 'calling out' or simply 'call out' is fine.

Comment: Either's fine .

Comment: There is a subtle difference there. `Calling` means that he came while you were still requesting assistance. `Call` implies that the request was complete.

Comment: 'heard me call' 'heard my calling' 'heard my call' : they all work. As commented above 'calling' is ongoing.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "my calling for help" would be better if it was a noun phrase, as it is the object of the verb heard . . .  so it would be "My husband came running when he heard my call for help".